# Copying absolute values of columns

Tags: excel

Hi i've got an excel file (file A) with multiple columns created using xlsxwriter.
However this column value outputs are based on a formula.

Now i'd like to copy this column values to another excel file i've created using xlsxriter / xlrd. If there anyway to copy JUST absolute values out?My attempts often copies the whole formula from the previous file A and hence I've got no values. Thanks!

Comment: Please share your efforts. [MCVE] And should this have a python tag?

Comment: If you created the file with XlsxWriter then the formula won't have a result that you can read/copy (apart from 0). See the [Formula Results](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-results) section of the XlsxWriter docs.